# Migration advice from SQL server 2000 bak

Tags: sql-server, migration

A small and old Windows 2003 server, just crashed; from the backup only the .bak files are available.
A new server will be built, however, as the database is very small (20MB) and the Windows server was also used for printing and file sharing (5 users), I was wondering what platform would be worth it to start from (server platform and SQL server version).
Maybe to make things easier it could be wise to use a simple Windows 7/8 machine with SQL server installed.
BTW, clients are running Access 2003 (ADODB/adp).

Your thoughts?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64730/discussion-on-question-by-riccardo-migration-advice-from-sql-server-2000-bak).